# How to get new answers to a question to replace/update the existing answers?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049267) was asked in Nov 2011 and the last answer was in Jan 2012. The answers may be way out of date now in Jan 2014.

How should one go about getting new updated answers?

Comment: Add a bounty to the question. Perhaps not a direct dupe, but it's in essence similar to [the problem raised here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: This particular question seems to be asking for an opinion.  If I found something similar posted in one of my favorite tags, I'd vote to close.

Comment: It's such a shame that stackoverflow has become so pedantic.  Even if it seems to be asking for an opinion, the question is still useful.  Rather than voting to close, how about suggesting to the author how they can improve the question?

Comment: Voting to close is a way to poke the author to improve the question.  I didn't say that I would not leave a comment (but I can't guarantee that I would for a question like this one).

Comment: IMHO - please leave comments!  In the past, I have had questions closed that seemed to meet the requirements so I had no idea why they were closed.  I'd guess that most authors don't want to write bad questions/answers, and really appreciate the feedback when they are doing things wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it some attention:

- Share it on Facebook, Reddit, or any other places where experts may see it and be interested in answering.
- Bring it to chat on the relevant site (or in [so]'s case, the relevant room), maybe someone there would be interested.
- Add a bounty on it, ask for up-to-date answers (there's a specific bounty reason for that).